# Would the Daniel cell work just as well if a solution of zinc ions wasn't used?

Tags: electrochemistry

I know that, in a Daniell cell, the zinc anode is immersed in a solution of zinc ions. As I see it, though, these ions are irrelevant to the reaction taking place.

Would the cell work just as well if the zinc was immersed in a solution of sodium chloride instead?

Comment: Can I make orange juice, if I use apples instead of oranges ? It would still be juice, just not orange one. The Daniell cell is defined as the system $\ce{Zn(s)|ZnSO4(aq)||CuSO4(aq)|Cu(s)}$. Your proposed cell would be still a galvanic cell, just not the Daniell one.

Comment: Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions are usually closed on the StackExchange network.  Aside of lack of expected explicit a priori effort, they are generally hard to work with, due possible question misinterpretation, needed clarification and  difficult estimation of the OP knowledge .  [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).
Describe the question well, search, think, refer and summarize.  Well elaborated questions have higher probability to  receive acceptable answers.

Comment: Using a different ion solution might lead to a different undesirable reaction with the ions of that solution. We use solutions with similar ions to minimize interference